# How to create an IPA and manifest.plist for over-the-air from the console xcodebuild

Tags: xcodebuild

i have a script that collects an ipa file in two steps.
The first step is to build the archive:

```python
def buildArchive(nameProject, typeMode, dirBuild, dirArch):
  print('[--] Run Build Archive')
  rArch = subprocess.run(['xcodebuild',
    'archive',
    '-verbose',
    '-scheme', '{}'.format(nameProject),
    '-configuration', '{}'.format(typeMode),
    '-derivedDataPath', '{}'.format(dirBuild),
    '-archivePath', '{}/project.xcarchive'.format(dirArch),
    '-allowProvisioningUpdates'],
    capture_output=True)
  if rArch.returncode != 0:
    if rArch.stderr:
      print('[EE] output: {}'.format(rArch.stdout.decode('UTF-8')))
      print('[EE] error: {}'.format(rArch.stderr.decode('UTF-8')))
    else:
      print('[EE] output: {}'.format(rArch.stdout.decode('UTF-8')))
    sys.exit(rArch.returncode)
```

The second step is to create an IPA file:

```python
def buildIpa(dirArch, dirDistr):
  print('[--] Run Build Ipa')
  rIpa = subprocess.run(['xcodebuild',
    '-exportArchive',
    '-verbose',
    '-archivePath', '{}/project.xcarchive'.format(dirArch),
    '-exportPath', '{}'.format(dirDistr),
    '-exportOptionsPlist', './{}'.format("ExportOptions.plist")],
    capture_output=True)
  if rIpa.returncode != 0:
    if rIpa.stderr:
      print('[EE] error: {}'.format(rIpa.stderr.decode('UTF-8')))
    else:
      print('[EE] output: {}'.format(rIpa.stdout.decode('UTF-8')))
    sys.exit(rIpa.returncode)
```

I think in the first step (building the archive) I need to add some keys to collect with additional information about the manifest. But I don't understand how to do it. Please tell me where you can read about it.
In Xcode, this is done through an additional option:
[image]

Comment: What is the Swift tag for?

Comment: not needed, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be simple. It is necessary to create an ipa file with additional parameters (over-the-air) once through XCode and copy the ExportOptions.plist file in the folder. It will already contain additional parameters.